# How to read the GSON String in C++

Tags: c++, json, gson

I have a Gson serialized string which is to to be read in C++ 
For example :

```
String jsonDealer = [{"dealerID":"VARSSWK103","dealerName":"Dealer ABC"},     {"dealerID":"VARSSTH008","dealerName":"Dealer XYZ"}]
```

How I can convert this to C++ object , so that I can retrieve the dealer ID and dealer name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[GSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GSON) is a *Java* library, to parse from and serialize into [JSON](http://www.json.org/) format.

So you want a C++ library handling JSON. There are many of them; I suggest using [jsoncpp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jsoncpp/)

Of course, you'll need to define your C++ application classes (e.g. your `Dealer`), but JsonCPP would make parsing JSON into your data fairly easy.

Comment: Will jsoncpp able to convert "Gson string" ... im little confused with Gson and Json.

Comment: Please define what you call *Gson string* ; consider that JSON is a standard format & notation...

Comment: i mean ,, i have a class in java which i parsed using Gson parser,,, and i have passed this string as an argument to my C++ function ,, which needs to de-serialize this string \

Comment: I don't understand your last comment. Classes are not parsed (except by the Java compiler parsing your Java source code). Remember that JSON is a notation or format. If the JSON representation is emitted = written by Java code (using Gson) it can be parsed = read by C++ code (using JsonCpp) and vice-versa (JSON format produced by C++ code using JsonCpp and consumed by Java code using GSON).